# For what choice of the basis atoms origin the Structure Factor is real?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, crystals, lattice-model, x-ray-crystallography

I have a Cuprite Structure:

[image]

Now, given that I described this structure as a Simple Cubic lattice with a 6 atoms basis, I have to choose the origin for these basis atoms such that the structure factor is real.

Is there a technique or some sort of useful information (e.g. symmetry properties etc..) in doing that or should I improvise and try different choices unitil I reach the result?

Thanks for the help.